# Customized Site Theme?

Tags: feature-request

I'm relatively new to the inner-workings of a Stack Exchange site, but I have noticed that a lot of the [other Stack Exchange sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites) have a customized look and feel, or theme.

Maybe it's not yet time for something like this, but I'll ask anyway. Is it possible to configure a theme for the Salesforce Stack Exchange site? If so, I'm sure we could come up with a ton of ideas for customization. If not, is this something that is possible after leaving the beta phase?

Comment: See [The 7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/). The site will receive a customized design once it leaves beta, but it is not too early to start discussion ideas now.

Comment: This is still a way off, but here's a great recent blog post from our lead designer on how he approaches the process:  http://www.8164.org/stack-exchange/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [FAQ](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/faq#sketchy), that comes when you leave beta.  We should definitely discuss ideas, though.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, we should definitely customize the theme. Not sure when the right time for this is - presumably during one of the transitions from private to public beta or public beta to release.

One way to do this would be to ask here on meta for theme mockups - community members with design skills could submit them as answers, and upvotes would do the rest...